# sql server script generated by PowerDesigner

Tags: java, sql, spring, powerdesigner

I have a PDM on PowerDesigner 15.1. And I generate a script with it for a SQL Server 2008R2 db.

So the generated script looks like something like this :

```
if exists (select 1 
    from sys.sysreferences r join sys.sysobjects o on (o.id = r.constid and o.type = 'F')     
    where r.fkeyid = object_id('TABLE1') and o.name = CONSTRAINT1') 
alter table TABLE1
    drop constraint CONSTRAINT1
go
```

This chunk of script is repeated for each table that I have.

After I have the creation of the table and the definitions of constraints.

When I want to execute this script with a `DataSourceInitializer` (provided by Spring), and the good JDBC driver, I've got this following error :

```
Failed to execute SQL script statement at line 5 of resource class path resource [create_tables_SQL_SERVER.sql]: if exists (select 1
```

I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write each statement in a single line or add a delimiter (default `;`) at the end of each statement:

```
if exists (select 1  from sys.sysreferences r join sys.sysobjects o on (o.id = r.constid and o.type = 'F') where r.fkeyid = object_id('TABLE1') and o.name = CONSTRAINT1') 
alter table TABLE1 drop constraint CONSTRAINT1
```

---

*For completeness, because the code explain it best:*
The magic is done by this code in `ResourceDatabasePopulator`: Line 171..178

```
    String delimiter = this.separator;
    if (delimiter == null) {
        delimiter = DEFAULT_STATEMENT_SEPARATOR; // ";"
        if (!containsSqlScriptDelimiters(script, delimiter)) {
            delimiter = "\n";
        }
    }
    splitSqlScript(script, delimiter, statements);
```